# Is there any way to sort data from a dynamic firebasedatabase path?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

This is the structure of my data:

[image]

```
SportType
  BE81I7B6FkQ2GQrymHRLBQqh8b63
   Burpees
   Mountain Climb
   Plank
   Prisoner Squats
   Sit Up
  PgYqYIWGHjRDKBLqyqXVg1iXGos2
   Burpees
    accountid:"PgYqYIWGHjRDKBLqyqXVg1iXGos2"
    sportname:"Burpees"
    totalcount:0
   Mountain Climb
   Plank
   Prisoner Squats
   Sit Up
```

using this reference:

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(URL).getReference("SportType");
```

to explore child we need to make an exact path, but in my case, there's child that named unique.

i try to order each sporttype (burpees, situp, etc) and display the rank.
(code below only to retrieve data, i haven't order it and display it)
To get each id's sporttype records, i try to loop the function with for function but it turn out not so effective. i want to know if there's a more effective solution for this problem.

here's the function i made:

```
private void manualOrder(){
    dialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
    dialog.show();

    idreference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            // get all the unique id path
            for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                accountKey = ds.getKey();
                allaccount.add(accountKey);
            }
            dialog.dismiss();

            clearsport();
            for (int i=0; i<allaccount.size(); i++){
                String key = allaccount.get(i);
                reference.child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        //Classify sporttype
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                            sport = ds.getValue(SportType.class);
                            if(sport.getSportname().equals("Burpees")){
                                burpees.add(sport);
                            }else if(sport.getSportname().equals("Plank")){
                                plank.add(sport);
                            }else if(sport.getSportname().equals("Sit Up")){
                                situp.add(sport);
                            }else if(sport.getSportname().equals("Prisoner Squats")){
                                prisonersquats.add(sport);
                            }else if(sport.getSportname().equals("Mountain Climb")){
                                mountainclimb.add(sport);
                            }else{
                                Log.d("sportname not supported","sportname not supported");
                            }

                            allsport.add(sport); // just to check everything recorded
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }

                });

            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });


}
```

i expect something more efficient like orderchildby function, but can't figure how to make the path..

Comment: To understand better, do you need to order the children under `SportType/BE81...8b63`?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how `reference` and `idreference` are initialized?

Comment: i need to order children under SportType (BE81..8b63, PGYQ..gos2) by one of the sport's totalcount (eg: burpees rank, so i need to order BE81..8b63, PGYQ..gos2, by burpees's totalcount).

Comment: my bad, for not mentioning idreference..

Comment: idreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(URL).getReference("SportyAccount");

it contain, the user's id just same like the sportType, so i take the list from that path just to make it clear for me